# Unhandled rejection MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am getting following error while i am trying to increment a field by a specified value in mongodb using $inc

"Unhandled rejection MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in '$inc' is not valid for storage."

Below is my code

```
APILog.update({ apiId: 1 }, {$inc:{"dataCount":10}});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which mongodb version and library are you using?

Comment: MongoDB shell version v3.4.2

Comment: Did you ever solve?

Answer (score 2):

You should include values as JSON in Mongo Query. Might be due to this you are facing an issue. Can you please try by updating your query as:

```
APILog.update({
  "apiId": 1
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "dataCount": 10
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into same exception and was able to solve this way.
Following is the syntax of executing a general command in mongodb, updated with your example data:

```
db.runCommand(
    update: "<replace-with-collection-name>",
    updates: [
        {
            q:{"apiId": 1}, u: {"$inc": {"dataCount": 10}}
        }
    ]
)
```

Escape the $ character as per rules of node.js, if needed.

Answer (score 1):

For those who want to increment and set both on update in nodejs with [mongodb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) npm package.

I had a similar error when i tried to [$set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) with [$inc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) so this is how i solved it:

```
db.collection("example").updateOne({
    "apiId": 1
},
{
    $set: {
        "updatedAt": ISODate()
    },
    $inc: {
        "dataCount": 10
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I came across this... I've found at least for me that it works to use brackets if you're doing an aggregation inside your update. Like so:

```
db.example.updateMany(
    {FirstRecord:{$in:recordids}},
    [{$set:{
        RecordCode:{
            $first:{
                $map:{
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
     }}]
 )
```

In my case I'm trying to update a field which is a code we will use later to match to other documents, and have a list of ObjectIds for the target records and a dictionary from ID to code. Anyway I found I received a similar error until I added the brackets around [{$set:{}}]